# If someone wanted to do a meta analysis would they be able to use a publication that does not have p-values listed in the publication?

Tags: p-value, meta-analysis, meta-regression

If someone wanted to do a meta analysis would they be able to use a publication that does not have p-values listed in the publication?

Does a meta analysis really need a publication to have a p-value?

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what the exact situation is? Are you trying to use a method for combining p-values but some primary studies do not present them?

Comment: The objective was to assess if an article is worthy for inclusion dependent on them mentioning p values or not. It clearly depends on the value/variable of interest as one user pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CrossValidated!

For every study you want to put into a meta-analysis, you (usually) need two things:

- An estimate of the effect (often standardized)
- An estimate of the standard error of the effect

That's all.

If the paper has the information that allows you to calculate those two things, you're good to go. That information might be: Means and standard deviations, or standard errors, or p-values, or t-statistics, or confidence intervals (possibly of a difference), etc.

(If you point us to the paper, we might be able to help.)